# Anti-Aliased line algorithm with thickness (on WriteableBitmap)

Tags: wpf, algorithm, drawing, antialiasing, writeablebitmap

I am looking for a code sample for an anti-aliased line drawing algorithm (e.g. Wu, Bresenham) that handles thickness. This is for use in a cross platform application using WPF/Silverlight's WriteableBitmap, however any C-based language will no doubt be useful.

I've googled this subject to death but as you can imagine there aren't many good code examples out there as drawing frameworks such as GDI/GDI+ handle this for you.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Library: http://www.antigrain.com/index.html Subject: http://www.antigrain.com/doc/introduction/introduction.agdoc.html#SUBPIXEL_BRESENHAM