# Setting line stroke thickness in WriteableBitmap DrawLine method

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, line, writeablebitmap

i am using WriteableBitmap to draw lines as

```
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp=new WriteableBitmap(500,500);
writeableBmp.DrawLineDDA(10, 20, 50, 70,myIntColor);
```

But here i am not getting any method to set the line stroke thickness. I want to set the line stroke thickness.Please help me,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look,

[Anti-Aliased line algorithm with thickness (on WriteableBitmap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079133/anti-aliased-line-algorithm-with-thickness-on-writeablebitmap)

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)